# Setting Environment Variables using IIS Administration API

Tags: rest, iis

Does anyone know how to set environment variables on an application pool using the IIS Administration REST API?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/api/application-pools

Comment: You can get hints from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/api-explorer/resource-manipulation

Comment: The IIS Management API provides a set of file APIs to interact directly with the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting environment variables using the Web API isn't currently possible.

If anyone else is interested in this feature, i've created a branch containing a first draft. Maybe i will submit a PR after some testing.

[My Branch](https://github.com/sevensolutions/IIS.Administration/tree/feature/app-pool-environment-variables)

You can then create an AppPool like this:

```
{
  "name": "Demonstration App Pool",
  "environment_variables": {
    "CONNECTION_STRING": "some value"
  }
}
```